# Can Dracula die?

Tags: horror, dracula

In many movies I have seen the Dracula extinguished. But we all know that Dracula was immortal. So, please tell me: can he die or not?

Comment: [There are different kinds of immortality](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Immortality)

Comment: @Kreiri So what about Kenny McCormack on South Park? :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the original Bram Stoker work, Dracula is destroyed at the very end.  And just as his body disintegrates, the hunters observe that he has a peaceful expression on his face.

So absolutely, Dracula can die.

Comment: This is interesting given that the burning process in the sun, while apparently painful, is quite fast. My sense has always been that he might find himself in a bad place in the afterlife which means that even someone who found the existence unpleasant and wished for peace is kind of out of luck and is putting off the inevitable.

Answer (score 7):

Techncially, no as the usual interpretation is that he is not alive in the first place (hence he is undead).

However, if the question is modified to can Dracula be destroyed then he is usually destroyed at the end of each film, whether he will be brought back usually depends on whether there is likely to be money in making a sequel.